# Is tawba acceptable for pre-marital sexual videos my boyfriend put on the internet?

Tags: sex, tawba, internet

I have committed illegal sexual relationship with my boyfriend and made some videos. Now he put those videos on the internet. Now I am very much depressed about what I did. Is my tawba acceptable?

Comment: Uh. @user14399, although your sin is awful, but Allah will forgive you if you indeed repent. / I am providing a short answer, God willing I will present it in some mins. Good luck mate.

Answer (score 3):

Although your sin as what you stated is considered as a major sin, but you ought to pay attention that Allah is Tavvab. In other word, it means He will accept the repentance. In the meantime, don’t forget that according to a verse of the holy Qur'an:

> قُلْ يَا عِبَادِيَ الَّذِينَ أَسْرَفُوا عَلَىٰ أَنفُسِهِمْ لَا
>   تَقْنَطُوا مِن رَّحْمَةِ اللَّـهِ ۚ إِنَّ اللَّـهَ يَغْفِرُ الذُّنُوبَ
>   جَمِيعًا ۚ إِنَّهُ هُوَ الْغَفُورُ الرَّحِيمُ ﴿٥٣﴾
>
> Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by
>   sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed, Allah forgives
>   all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful." (53)

As a concise answer:

> A major sin is one that being punished in hell is promised to its
>   committer in the Quran or ahadith. (There are also other criteria for
>   a sin being a major one). Also minor sins turn into major sins when
>   committed repeatedly (when insisted on by the sinner).
>
> In the Quran, Allah has promised to forgive all sins if one truly
>   repents to him. Regarding Haqqullah (Obligation to Allah) repentance
>   would be to make up for the past and saying Istiqfar while regarding
>   Haqqunnas (Obligation to people) it would be doing Istiqfar, giving
>   the person back his rights and striving to obtain his satisfaction.

---

For more info. I recommend you to read the following source.

**Source:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa914)
- [www.tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/39:53)

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all you should know that one of Allah's names is the all forgiving!

So if you do sincere repentance from what you did Allah may forgive you.

Scholars (Sunni) say that a sincere repentance would make sins disappear even for sins which should be (but are not) punished according to shari'a (see the links below in Arabic)! This would mean you should do repentance and expiation and real regretting and turn the sins into good deeds like praying, fasting,..., doing good things, helping: Being a good muslim and not redoing what those sins!

Because of the following Verses:

1. Surat [at-Tawba](http://quran.com/9/104) (9:104)
2. Surat [al-Furqan](http://quran.com/25/70)(25:70)
3. Surat [ash-Shura](http://quran.com/42/25)(42:25)

Verses 1 and 3 just tell as that Allah accept repentance (if it is sincere as explained above) while Verse 2 tells us that Allah even turn sins into good deeds if one is faithful and and repent sincerly!

And here some fatwas in Arabic about [sincere repentance](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/66209), repentance [from major sins](http://www.islamtoday.net/istesharat/quesshow-70-67444.htm) and [how to clean oneself from sins](http://qaradawi.net/new/all-fatawa/7267-2014-05-08-19-22-09).

And Allah knows best!

Answer (score 1):

It's always Tauba.
Allaah Rabbul `alameen will forgive any sins except the Sins of Shirk and the sins of mocking Rasulallaah Sallallaahu 'alaihi wasallam.
And even after that, I think, there is always room for Repentance (Tauba).

May Allaah accept your repentance.